# Can electrons be isolated from atoms?

Tags: electrons, superconductivity

Can electrons be isolated from atoms? If its possible,why cant we isolate pile of electrons and put them in a vaccum container,if we can do this we can achieve super conductance because there are no positive lattice in a vaccum container full of electrons.no positive lattice implies electron don't collide with any positive lattice so the vaccum container has got zero resistance.

Comment: Like in vacuum tube electronics?

Comment: not sure, I am just an amateur.I don't think you have any problem understanding my question.

Comment: have a read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode-ray_tube

Comment: How did the old CRT TV’s work?

Comment: The sketch where Conan O'Brien and Jim Carrey discuss the storage of a single electron in a Penning trap has unfortunately vanished from YouTube. I believe the paper they read was about the first trap that stored a single electron for more than a year; the birthday party that the researchers threw for their electron wasn't part of their publication record.

Answer (score 1):

From the [link I gave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode-ray_tube) in the comments to your question

> The cathode-ray tube (CRT) is a vacuum tube that contains one or more electron guns

and the [electron gun](http://An%20electron%20gun%20(also%20called%20electron%20emitter)%20is%20an%20electrical%20component%20in%20some%20vacuum%20tubes%20that%20produces%20a%20narrow,%20collimated%20electron%20beam%20that%20has%20a%20precise%20kinetic%20energy.) referred there

> An electron gun (also called electron emitter) is an electrical component in some vacuum tubes that produces a narrow, collimated electron beam that has a precise kinetic energy.

the answer is yes, electron beams have been used for about a century, let alone the beams in the electron positron colliders at SLAC and CERN.

Comment: but can that be used as a super conductor?

Comment: superconductors have a definite existence in physics and are not  what you envisage. see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconductivity The beam of electrons conducts as much current as the circuit allows, and in cathode ray tubes it was used in televisions before the advent of pixels.